# Angular Js Directive to add dynamic bootstrap classes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

We are implementing reusable code in our application for this purpose we have created a simple directive which displays content.

**Directive Code:**

```
angular.module("newsStore.moduleDirectives", [])
    .directive('renderAboutContent', ['aboutService', renderAboutContent]);

function renderAboutContent(aboutService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'templates/about.html',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            aboutService.getAboutContent()
                .then(function (results) {
                    scope.aboutList = results.aboutContent.listItems;
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log('controller error', error);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="col-md-12 aboutUs-ph padT10 content-ph_abt" ng-repeat="content in aboutList">
    <div class="col-md-2 form-group" ng-if="content.image">
        <img src="{{content.image}}" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <span class="guidedTourText"><b>{{content.title}}</b></span>
        <br>
        <span>{{content.description}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Question:**

In the above HTML you can see col-md-2 and col-md-9 inside col-md-12, we want the col-md-2 and col-md-9 width come up as dynamic as sometimes image may not be present in the col-md-2 so in that case text should occupy col-md-12 not col-md-9.

Thanks guys for the answers, this solutions works in this scenario, but one question let's say I have three div elements, and three of them occupies 4, 4 ,4 if the content is present. Let's say if the content is not present in the last div then the remaining two div's should take 6,6 and vice versa. We want this to be implemented from the directive rather than from the html.

Let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: this is where you might find ng-class to be useful.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use ng-class in this instance?

Comment: you are not clear, is this should work in your present exemple, or this a totally different scenario ?

Comment: Agreed, OP is vampiring the original question

Comment: I did say that the solution which you have provided works in the current scenario, I am asking about another case where we might three different div elements.

Comment: As I said in my question we are implementing a reusable component for our application so we need that to be a generic one.

Comment: @scniro buddy I am just tying to achieve better solutions using directive, if you think this too much then please don't answer the questions on stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) may be leveraged here to solve this. Observe the following...

```
ng-class="{'col-md-12': !content.image, 'col-md-9': !!content.image}"
```

For some additional reading, this popular blog post is a great reference for understanding the usages offered by this directive: [The Many Ways To Use ngClass](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass)

Comment: Thanks @thomas this one works in this scenario, but one question let's say I have three div elements, and three of them occupies 4, 4 ,4 if the content is present. Let's say if the content is not present in the last div then the remaining two div's should take 6,6 and vice versa.

Comment: so you use exactly the same method, ng-if combined to conditionnal ng-class

Comment: I didn't get what your trying to say, can you expain that in your answer?

Comment: as a minor enhancement/alternative you can represent this in a ternary style as `ng-class="content.image ? 'col-md-9' : 'col-md-12'"`

Comment: not understanding the downvote cast here. This does solve the _original_ question. Perhaps including some basic explanation and a resource could prevent such votes